# Facebook API, Javascript SDK & variable scope

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've got a problem of variable scope with this code:

```
var likesString = "";

var getLikes = function() {
  friend_ids = ["me", "123456789", "0987654321"];
  likesString = "";

  var likesArray = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < friend_ids.length; i++) {
    FB.api('/'+ friend_ids[i] +'/likes', function(response) {
      var tmpLikesString = "";
      if (response.data) {
        likes = response.data;
        var j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < likes.length; j++) {
          if (likes[j]["category"] == "Movie") {
            tmpLikesString = likes[j]["id"];
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Error looking for likes");
      }
      likesArray.push(tmpLikesString);
      console.log('In FB.api:'+  likesArray);
    });
    console.log('Out FB.api:'+  likesArray);
  }
  likesString = likesArray.join(',');
  console.log("likes : " + likesString);
 };
```

Inside FB.api, my var "likesArray" works, but when I'm out of it, it's like nothing happen to it…

The output if it can help to understand:

```
In FB.api:
In FB.api:,
In FB.api:,,
In FB.api:,,,208509052512525
In FB.api:,,,208509052512525,
In FB.api:,,,208509052512525,,153960391321494
(3)Out FB.api:
likes :
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you have a scope issue, I think you have a timing issue.

I expect that the `FB.api` call is *asynchronous*, am I right? (I haven't done any any Facebook programming.) That means that code after your `FB.api` call will run *before* code within the callback you're giving `FB.api`. But you're using `likesArray` in the code following the call, when it will still be empty.

It's like doing this:

```
var a = 1;
setTimeout(function() {
    a = 2;
}, 10);
alert(a); // alerts "1"
```

...because that, too, is asynchronous. You'll need to change your logic so that the code you currently have in the `getLikes` function *after* the `FB.api` call is instead called when the `FB.api` function calls your callback.

Again using the simplified example for clarity, basically, the equivalent of moving the `alert`:

```
var a = 1;
setTimeout(function() {
    a = 2;
    alert(a); // alerts "2"
}, 10);
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it. I'll tell you if it works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Yes because it has the scope of that function. So you need to reurn it so that it can be accessed

```
  oahuLikesString = likesArray.join(',');
  console.log("likes : " + likesString);
  return likesArray;
 };

var likesArray = getLikes();
```